# Find Element in XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<List>
  <Element>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <property>19</property>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <property>11</property>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <property>5</property>
  </Element>
</List>
```

No I like my code to give me the Element with the ID 3.

I tried this:

```
var node = doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Elements().Where(x=>x.Name == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()!=null).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this Exception occured:

An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Private.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
Name cannot begin with the '3' character, hexadecimal value 0x33

How can I get the third Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are comparing the name of the XMLElement to your `id`, and XML specification states that the name of an element cannot begin with a number. So instead of comparing to the name, compare to the value like so:

```cs
var node = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.Elements()
         // I Changed 'x.Name' to 'x.Value' here
        .Where(x => x.Value == id.ToString())
    .FirstOrDefault()!=null)
.FirstOrDefault();
```